# Azure Service Bus - Using DateTime in Topic/Subscription SqlFilter in .NET

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

How do you use DateTime in a SqlFilter for Topics/Subscriptions?

I have this message:

```
var message = new BrokeredMessage();
message.Properties["datetime"] = DateTime.Now;
```

I also have this SqlFilter:

```
var sqlFilter = new SqlFilter("datetime > '2016-06-06'");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work, you need to add a parameter to the filter.

```
var filter = new SqlFilter(" datetime >= @datetime");
filter.Parameters.Add("@datetime", DateTime.Parse("2016-06-06"));
```

Comment: Is that use the ticks of the datetime ?

Comment: Are you asking if that is using ticks to do the comparison? This would use whatever .NET's underlying DateTime comparison would use.

Comment: So maybe you don't even need to add a parameter, just having a sql filter like that `new SqlFilter($"datetime >= {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");` ?

Comment: But the SQL filter will not interpret DateTimes when they are a string, so the interpolation, will not work.This `SqlFilter($"datetime >= {DateTime.Now.Ticks}");` isn't any different from this `SqlFilter("datetime > '2016-06-06'");`